# Reading CSV with mixed type data

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I need to read the following `csv` file in MATLAB:

```
2009-04-29 01:01:42.000;16271.1;16271.1
2009-04-29 02:01:42.000;2.5;16273.6
2009-04-29 03:01:42.000;2.599609;16276.2
2009-04-29 04:01:42.000;2.5;16278.7
...
```

I'd like to have three columns:
timestamp;value1;value2

I tried the approaches described here:
[Reading date and time from CSV file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641519/reading-date-and-time-from-csv-file-in-matlab)
modified as:

```
filename = 'prova.csv';  
fid = fopen(filename, 'rt');  
a = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f', ...  
        'Delimiter',';', 'CollectOutput',1);  
fclose(fid);
```

But it returs a 1x2 cell, whose first element is `a{1}='ÿþ2'`, the other are empty.

I had also tried to adapt to my case the answers to these questions:
[importing data with time in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200856/importing-data-with-time-in-matlab?rq=1)
[Read data files with specific format in matlab and convert date to matal serial time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534866/read-data-files-with-specific-format-in-matlab-and-convert-date-to-matal-serial)
but I didn't succeed.

How can I import that `csv` file?

**EDIT** After the answer of @macduff i try to copy-paste in a new file the data reported above and use:

```
a = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f','Delimiter',';');
```

and it works.
Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem because I have to process `csv` files generated automatically, which seems to be the cause of the strange MATLAB behavior.

Comment: Perhaps Matlab is choking on the first line for some reason? Did you do a diff of the generated file and the one that you made with a copy-paste? Can you copy/paste programmatically from Matlab and make it work, too?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying:

```
a = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f','Delimiter',';');
```

For me I get:

```
a = 

{4x1 cell}    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

So each element of `a` corresponds to a column in your csv file.  Is this what you need?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but from your code i get: `a = 
    {1x1 cell}    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're going about it the right way. The example you provide poses no problems here, I get the output you desire. What's in the 1x2 cell?

If I were you I'd try again with a smaller subset of the file, say 10 lines, and see if the output changes. If yes, then try 100 lines, etc., until you find where the 4x1 cell + 4x2 array breaks down into the 1x2 cell. It might be that there's an empty line or a single empty field or whatever, which forces `textscan` to collect data in an additional level of cells.

Note that `'CollectOutput',1` will collect the last two columns into a single array, so you'll end up with 1 cell array of 4x1 containing strings, and 1 array of 4x2 containing doubles. Is that indeed what you want? Otherwise, see @macduff's post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first element of the cell is `a{1}='ÿþ2'` the others are empty....I tried to adde more data to the original file (10 lines, 50,100...) but nothing change....If I copy-paste the whole data set (about 20 thousand rows) in another `csv`it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've had to parse large files like this, and I found I didn't like textscan for this job.  I just use a basic while loop to parse the file, and I use datevec to extract the timestamp components into a 6-element time vector.

```
%% Optional: initialize for speed if you have large files
n = 1000  %% <# of rows in file - if known>
timestamp = zeros(n,6);
value1 = zeros(n,1);
value2 = zeros(n,1);

fid = fopen(fname, 'rt');
if fid < 0
    error('Error opening file %s\n', fname); % exit point
end

cntr = 0
while true
    tline = fgetl(fid);  %% get one line
    if ~ischar(tline), break; end; % break out of loop at end of file
    cntr = cntr + 1;

    splitLine = strsplit(tline, ';');  %% split the line on ; delimiters
    timestamp(cntr,:) = datevec(splitLine{1}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'); %% using datevec to parse time gives you a standard timestamp vector
    value1(cntr) = splitLine{2};
    value2(cntr) = splitLine{3};
 end

%% Concatenate at the end if you like
result = [timestamp  value1  value2];
```